# How do I compare two arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops

Suppose I have two arrays

```
array1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
array2=np.array([11,1,2,4,10,60,0,3,20,33])
```

I want to compare the two arrays and store the values that are bigger. I want to write a code that will check the first element of array1 with the first element of array2 and store the greatest value between them in a new array and so on.

I tried it with this code

```
array3=[]
i=0
while i<=len(array1):
    if array1[i]>array2[i]:
        array3.append(i)
```

However, the code doesn't give any output and keeps on running. The two array in question that i want to work with are very big so will a normal loop method work for big arrays as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using numpy, using numpy all the way is preferable. It will be faster, and use less memory, than the iterative approach (and is more readable, too).

```
np.max([array1, array2], axis=0)
```

Your loop is infinite because your `i` never changes. If you fix that (either by adding `i += 1` or by using `for i in range(0, len(array1)):`), you will only be appending elements where `array1` one is larger, and leaving out any pairs where they are equal, or where the `array2` one is larger: an `else:` would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like `numpy.maximum`:

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([ 1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6, 7, 8, 9,  10])
array2 = np.array([11, 1, 2, 4, 10, 60, 0, 3, 20, 33])

np.maximum(array1, array2)
# array([11,  2,  3,  4, 10, 60,  7,  8, 20, 33])
```

Comment: Huh, `np.maximum`. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

First, the reason it keeps going is that you are not incrementing your iterator `i`.

Second, currently you are adding the index of the greater number, and not the greater number. Try the following code(pure python):

```
array3 = []
i = 0
while i < len(array1):
    if array1[i] > array2[i]:
        array3.append(array1[i])
    else:
        array3.append(array2[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
import numpy as np

array1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
array2=np.array([11,1,2,4,10,60,0,3,20,33])

array3=[]
i=0
while i<len(array1):
    if array1[i]>array2[i]:
        array3.append(array1[i])
    else:
        array3.append(array2[i])
    i += 1

print(array3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to do this with a list comprehension.  This would work assuming the arrays are always the same size.

```
[max([array1[i],array2[i]]) for i in range(len(array1))]
```